# To forward a JSON file to other Address with Express js

Tags: json, express

Just starting to learn express. Would wish to forward a json file to another location for processing/ingestion that i recieved from a request from webhook using POST url endpoint.

I am planning to pass this json file to a cpp  program

I have the following code

```
var request = require('request'),,
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');
    http = require('http');

const port = 5000;

var app = express();

// for json parser
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/gethub', function(req, res) {

    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    console.log("Got header: " + res.getHeaderNames());
    console.log("Got status Message: " + res.statusMessage );

    var data = req.body;
    var name = data.pusher.name;
    var node_id   = data.sender.node_id;

    res.status(200).send(res.json( { name : name,
                                     Nodeid : node_id   });                                                  
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        var host = server.address().address
        var portid = server.address().port

        console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, portid)
        console.log("App listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

THanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean with 'forward' ?

Comment: Outside of the node application, how would you normally feed this json file to the other program?

Comment: @Evert I intend to pass this json information to my main program which is in C++

Answer (score 0):

Think of `Express` as a framework that behaves as a web server. What you really are doing is writing an `API` listening in the port 5000 in your case. The function seems ok so it will be accesible while making a HTTP request using the POST method.

[Express docs about routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths)